Call ExifTool from Azure Functions
I'm using ExifTool to update image metadata from a .NET 8 azure function app. I'm executing the exe file via NExifTool wrapper library. It works correctly but at random times it takes more than 30 seconds to complete a task where the normal execution time is about 2-3 seconds. When there is a batch of updates like 40 files, it proceses 37 files as expected and makes us wait for 40-50 seconds for the last files. It happens as well for single executions or keep awake calls (not every time but evere 5-6 times).
I use the Windows Stand-Alone Executable version since it is not possible to install PERL. Can it be related to perl runtime?
Any help is appreciated.
var updates = new List<Operation>();


// list of set operations   
updates.Add(new SetOperation(new Tag("CopyrightNotice", "2024 Company")));


stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var writeResult = await _exifTool.WriteTagsAsync(stream, updates, cancellationToken);



To integrate the ExifTool functionality into an Azure Function to update image metadata the ExifTool executable (exiftool.exe) is must be included in your Azure Function's.
The below code interacte with the exiftool.exe and i used this sample example  from this git.
     const string c_exeName = "exiftool.exe";
        const string c_arguments = @"-stay_open 1 -@ - -common_args -charset UTF8 -G1 -args";
        const string c_exitCommand = "-stay_open\n0\n-execute\n";
        const int c_timeout = 30000;    // in milliseconds
        const int c_exitTimeout = 15000;

        static Encoding s_Utf8NoBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        Process m_exifTool;
        StreamWriter m_in;
        StreamReader m_out;

        public ExifTool()
        {
            // Prepare process start
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(c_exeName, c_arguments);
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.StandardOutputEncoding = s_Utf8NoBOM;

            try
            {
                m_exifTool = Process.Start(psi);
                if (m_exifTool == null || m_exifTool.HasExited)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to launch ExifTool!");
                }
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception err)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to load ExifTool. 'ExifTool.exe' should be located in the same directory as the application or on the path.", err);
            }

            // ProcessStartInfo in .NET Framework doesn't have a StandardInputEncoding property (though it does in .NET Core)
            // So, we have to wrap it this way.
            m_in = new StreamWriter(m_exifTool.StandardInput.BaseStream, s_Utf8NoBOM);
            m_out = m_exifTool.StandardOutput;
        }

        public void GetProperties(string filename, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> propsRead)
        {
            LogMessage(filename);
            m_in.Write(filename);
            m_in.Write("\n-execute\n");
            m_in.Flush();

            for (; ; )
            {
                var line = m_out.ReadLine();
                if (line.StartsWith("{ready")) break;
                if (line[0] == '-')
                {
                    int eq = line.IndexOf('=');
                    if (eq > 1)
                    {
                        string key = line.Substring(1, eq - 1);
                        string value = line.Substring(eq + 1).Trim();
                        propsRead.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
                    }
                }
            


Refer to this so for Embedding Perl Interpreter
Refer to this link to How To Run PERL Scripts In C#

Thanks for the reply, but my program is actually working but I'm facing very long execution times randomly. I'll try the stay open option as soon as I can and let you know the result.

Glad to know it is working. Ok let know
